# how self can be passed while inheritance?

Tags: python, self

```
class Trout(Fish):
    def __init__(self, water = "freshwater"):
        self.water = water
        super().__init__(self)
```

In this line `super().__init__(self)` how is the `self` parameter passed to the function?

Comment: What do you mean how is it passed?

Comment: super().__init__(self), in this line how self works?? @Carcigenicate

Answer (score 1):

Say you have the code

```
f = Trout()
```

Behind the scenes, this is roughly equivalent to

```
f = Trout.__new__()
Trout.__init__(f)
```

Inside `Trout.__init__`, `super()` returns a proxy object that represents the appropriate class in the method resolution order of `Trout`; you don't actually have to pass `self` as an explicit argument; `super().__init__` defaults to a bound method with `self` already present.

Comment: but what if, there is two argument other than self in __init__ of base class?? will it give error??

Comment: No; any arguments passed to `Trout()` are implicitly passed to `__new__` and `__init__` as well. However, if `Trout.__init__` is defined to take additional arguments that are intended to be passed to `Fish.__init__`, you are responsible for passing them explicitly when you call `super().__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

The object calling the method is implicitly (automatically) the first argument to the method.  This is an agreement the language makes with itself.

In practical terms, assume you have an object `obj` of some type that has a method `stuff` that takes a simple Boolean argument.  You invoke the method as

```
obj.stuff(True)
```

If this were a "normal" function, you would invoke it as

```
stuff(obj, True)
```

... but that's not how the syntax of classes and objects works.  In any case, the function/method header looks the same:

```
def stuff(self, flag):
```

The difference here is that the each object class can have a method `stuff`, and we don't have to give them different names.  When we use class methods, the compiler knows which one to use by looking at the class of the invoking object.

---

In the specific case of the `__init__` method, the object is created immediately upon entry and assigned to `self`.  This is *another* automatic agreement the language makes with itself: this specially-named function includes an invisible creation of a default object when you enter.

Comment: super().__init__(self), in this line how self works??